# Regarding stacked chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I just want to implement a stacked bar chart  using chart.js
Is there any way to do the same.
Please Help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by "do the same".

Please try the following example:

[**Chart.StackedBar.js**](https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.StackedBar.js/blob/master/samples/stacked-bar.html)

Comment: Hey Buddy Thanks for reply,  i just want to implement stacked bar chart using chart.js only , So is there any way to do that.